# Angular 2 Route - Smooth Page Transition

Tags: angular, transition, router

I am afraid facing some issues implementing smooth page transition in Angular 2

what we are after is a smooth page transition from current to a new route

<------------------------------------sliding left

```
   <----- current route -------> <----- new route -------> 

           |<----- screen display ------->|
```

More information

A. We currently have a background component which is outside router-outlet, whenever a route change happens we change the file name of the background image.

B. During the route change we see the content the current route leaving below the screen while the new content arriving from the top. What should ideally happen is the current screen to slide left and new screen to slide left from the right hand side. And the same is not happening for background image

C. is there a way out-of-the-box to order a route parent-child-grandChild where by if you go from 
Parent to Child

<------------------------------------sliding left

<----- Parent child -------> <----- child route ------->

```
               |<----- screen display ------->|
```

and if you go from Child to Parent

```
                      sliding right------------------------------------>
```

<----- Parent child -------> <----- child route ------->

```
               |<----- screen display ------->|
```

Comment: Animation support for route changes is work in progress AFAIK.

Comment: See also https://github.com/matsko/angular-connect-demos

Comment: did you ever solve this? I have similar requirements, but can't differentiate navigating from child to parent or from parent to child. This should trigger different transitions, but I can only do it one way for one component.